# How does one access the Spidermonkey VM from within C++ code in cocos2d-x v3?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

Cocos2d-x v3 seems to have the Spidermonkey VM built in.

In a Cocos2d-x c++ project, how does one access the VM, to evaluate javascript expressions in it ?

I couldn't find any documentation about this - there is documentation about how to create javascript projects, but not about how to just access the VM in isolation from a C++ project.